# Apply css styles to layers in openlayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, css

define layers and styles using openlayers3 API.
I need to apply css styles for layers.for that code is in below used

```
//applying styles for wms layer
var fill = new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(237, 26, 170, 0.82)'});
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#4A12ED',width: 1.25});
var text = new ol.style.Text({color: '#F21A6C'});

var styles = [new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    fill: fill,
                    stroke: stroke,
                    radius: 5
                }),
                fill: fill,
                stroke: stroke,
            })];

var wms = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({title: "Population Density",url: 'http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms',params: {LAYERS: 'gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000'}}),
    style: styles
});

/*****************************************************************************/
//applying styles for unescap layer

var unescap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({url: 'http://203.159.29.11:8200/geoserver/unescap/wms?',params: {LAYERS: 'unescap:rg_di_any_all'}}),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#319FD3',width: 1}),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(17, 224, 36, 0.66)'}),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#ff0'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#09C',width: 3})
        })
    })
});
```

but styles are not applied 
error messages are not available in console
I want to know what is wrong with this code and how to apply styles properly.

Comment: You can only style features on the client side. A WMS server will send out images with predefined rendering. You can only alter these styles on the server side, in this case in the geoserver layer configuration (you will need admin privileges for this). You can only apply CSS styles to the images, which can be applied on an <img> element.

Comment: is there any code sample for do this (style the wms layer using client side script)

Comment: Use the CSS reference list: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/. Note that you can't change specific features in the image, just the whole image. Also, there are only a few image manipulation operations, and only in CSS3.